# Turn off, remove, or hide row numbers in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns.

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "round"          "mean pop. size"
```

When I view it R automatically adds row numbers.

```
> head(df)
  round mean pop. size
1     1             50
2     2             50
3     3             50
4     4             50
5     5             50
6     6             50
```

The row numbers are redundant, and I would like "turn them off" for this data frame. It seems that this is possible, because when I look at `mtcars`, there are no row numbers.

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I have tried

```
row.names(df) <- df$round
rownames(df) <- df$round
row.names(df) <- NULL
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

Comment: Theses are not "row numbers" but rather row names. Thus, for both `df` *and* `mtcars` you *do* see the row names.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, That's why I thought setting `row.names` or `rownames` would prevent R from adding extra numbers when I view the data frame. But it didn't.

Comment: `df$round` is also numbers. So you are setting numbers instead of numbers... Try for example `row.names(df) <- "a"`

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I hadn't realised that `mtcars` doesn't actually have a column for the car names; that's added by R when you view `mtcars`. And the reason that names are added instead of numbers is, of course, because `row.names` has been set to the car names.